# Does pcap_findalldevs() in WinPcap work for IPv6 in Windows10?

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, winpcap

I'm checking whether `pcap_findalldevs` can find IPv6 devices in Windows10
I'm not sure because Windows 10 doesn't seem one of supported platforms according to the homepage
(https://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm)

> Supported platforms:
> Windows NT4/2000
> Windows XP/2003/Vista/2008/Win7/2008R2/Win8 (x86 and x64)

I checked it out as below steps

(1) download developer's pack : https://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm
(2) open cygwin
(3) mv WpdPack\Examples-pcap\iflist
(4) build and run

As you see below result, it succeeds finding IPv4 devices
but it doesn't provides enough information for IPv6 devices
"Realtek USB NIC" is the device for IPv6

```sh
C:\cygwin64\home\WpdPack\Examples-pcap\iflist> iflist.exe
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
{6BA7B1CA-9393-4747-A1C7-BAFA5BF3CF0F}
Description: Microsoft                                                                                                                          Loopback: no
Address Family: #2
Address Family Name: AF_INET
Address: 10.177.98.131
Netmask: 0.0.0.0
Broadcast Address: 0.0.0.0

{6C5D9B8C-CA69-4E39-9946-A2CC10072117}
Description: Realtek USB NIC
Loopback: no

{1E922BCB-F3EF-4DC8-94A7-DCF1349730B4}
Description: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter
Loopback: no
Address Family: #2
Address Family Name: AF_INET
Address: 192.168.0.1
Netmask: 0.0.0.0
Broadcast Address: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

WinPcap is a dead product.  Even the WinPcap advise switching to Npcap.  From the [WinPcap news](https://www.winpcap.org/news.htm):

> 15 September 2018
> WinPcap, though still available for download (v4.1.3), has not seen an upgrade in many years and there are no road map/future plans
> to update the technology. While community support may persist,
> technical oversight by Riverbed staff, responses to questions posed by
> Riverbed resources, and bug reporting are no longer available.
> Gordon Lyon, Nmap project founder, has created Npcap, a packet capture library for Windows, that includes WinPcap compatibility and
> may be a suitable replacement for WinPcap and WinPcap Pro. Information
> can be found at https://nmap.org/npcap/.

I would suggest looking into Npcap instead: https://nmap.org/npcap/guide/npcap-devguide.html